# Show that the measure $h(E)= \int_{E} \frac{1}{x} dx$ on Borel sets is invariant under dilations

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $E\subset(0, \infty)$ be a Borel set and measure $h(E)= \int_{E} \frac{1}{x} dx$ where the integral is Lebesgue. Given $a \in (0,\infty)$, show that
>
> $h(E)=h(aE)$

First, note that that $h(aE)$ and $h(E)$ agree when $E$ is an interval. Also, I know that this is a Haar measure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) so that it is left-translation-invariant. Is that right? How I can prove that?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but $h(E) = h(aE)$ is not true in general? Set $E = (0,1)$ and, say, $a = 100$.

Comment: @LionelRicci  The set is Borel , not an interval. The integral is not the Reiman integral , it is the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: An interval is a Borel set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems all you need to do is to use the change of variable formula, $x=at$: 
$$h(aE) = \int_{aE}\frac{1}{x}\,dx =\int_E \frac{1}{at}\,a\,dt = h(E)$$
If you are unsure about change of variables with arbitrary Borel set present, write the integral in the (logically equivalent) way
$$h(aE) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}\chi_{aE}(x) \,dx =\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{at}\chi_{aE}(at)\,a\,dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}\chi_{E}(t)\,dt = h(E)$$